# Java: How can you store a very big number if it cannot be store in any primitive data type?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

How can you store a very big number in Java, if it cannot be stored in any primitive data type and you are not allowed to use any `BigDecimal`, `BitInteger` like data types.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` if it's whole and `BigDecimal` if it isn't.

Comment: @pbabcdefp OP said it cannot be stored in any data type.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I assume the OP meant it cannot be stored in any primitive type. We need more clarity on the question.

Comment: How to store a number if you cannot store it? You cannot. Obviously.

Comment: Yes @MarounMaroun , if  we cannot be stored in any primitive type and we don't have java like BigDecimal,BigInteger  then how to store or handle these kind of computation.

Comment: Well you can implement your own biginteger-alike, e.g. use an array of ints or bytes and store each digit in a separate byte? You'd then have to implement any arithmetic operation you need manually, e.g. add-with-carry, long-division. This will depending on your operation requirements and efficiency requirements e.g. whether you need to minimise storage (a single decimal digit per byte is still wasteful).

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger` for integral types, `BigDecimal` for unbounded precision decimal types.

Comment: "cannot be stored in any data type"

Comment: BigInteger and BigDecimal can store as much data as your Java heap allows.

Comment: And if either are not "large enough", apfloat can do that for you...

Comment: I am here searching for technique to store large value without using java BigInterger or BigDecimal